# Can't set full range on QSpinBox

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a QSpinBox that accepts all numbers, but I'm having some trouble with hte maximums

```
 sbox = QSpinBox(self)
 sbox.setRange(-sys.maxint/88-1, sys.maxint/86)
 sbox.setValue(int(setting.value))
```

I wanted to just use `sbox.setRange(-sys.maxint-1, sys.maxint)` but then I couldn't enter anything, if I increase the range any more than above the whole spinner freaks out. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that accepts all numbers

I assume you mean all *integers* rather than all numbers?

Remember that although PyQt is written in Python, the underlying Qt library is written in C++ so it most likely is limited to fixed-size integers of a certain width (for example 32-bit or 64-bit). If you try to use numbers close to the limits then some internal calculations in `QSpinBox` might overflow and wrap around which could explain the unusual behaviour you see.

To allow any integers at all use a [QLineEdit](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlineedit.html) and then parse the contents to a Python integer using the `int` function. This will allow all integers to be entered (you can even go above `sys.maxint`). You will lose the spin arrows though.